# Alt-gr not working in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I just installed the hortonworks sandbox on VirtualBox 4.3. Being used to azerty keyboards, I changed the file `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` like this :

```
KEYTABLE="fr"
MODEL="pc105+inet"
LAYOUT="fr"
KEYBOARDTYPE="pc"
```

I also tried `loadkeys fr`.

It works fine, except for characters requiring the `alt-gr` keystroke (like @, | or #). The keyboard itself is not deficient, as I can type these symbols outside the vm (the host key is not `alt-gr`).

I found mentions of this problem elsewhere (like [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=10014&highlight=backslash)), but didn't come accross a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same Problem and found a solution here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022454

Put short: 
Change the keyboard style on your underlying system to **ENG (United States)** (assuming you're using Windows 8.1 like me, but it might work on other systems too).

Explanation:
When you type "xev" on the terminal in CentOS and press down the altgr-key you will most likely see that two events are triggered, "shift level 3" (or something like that) AND "control_l" (or something like that). The control_l event comes from the underlying system's keyboard layout and won't be sent to the VM when using english keyboard layout. Weird, but it worked for me and to me it's the simplest solution and does not involve editing and creating config files on the guest system. ;)